# What is the determinant of cofactor matrix of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

For an $n \times n$ square matrix $A$, can determinant of its cofactor matrix (matrix consisting of cofactors of the elements of $A$) be expressed in terms of $\det(A)$ and $n$ ?

Comment: What is $\det(A^{-1})$ when $A$ is invertible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A(\operatorname{com}A)^T = \det (A) I_n$, $$\det (A) \det (\operatorname{com}A) = (\det(A))^n$$

Now it remains to check cases, whether $A$ is invertible or not.

If $\operatorname{rank} A =n$, $A$ is invertible and $\det (\operatorname{com}A) = (\det(A))^{n-1}$

If $\operatorname{rank} A = n-1$, $A(\operatorname{com}A)^T=0$. As a result, $\operatorname{Im}((\operatorname{com}A)^T)\subset \ker A $.

Hence $\dim \operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{com}A)= \dim \operatorname{Im}((\operatorname{com}A)^T)\leq \dim \ker A =1$ and $\det \operatorname{com}A = 0$

If $\operatorname{rank} A \leq n-2$, $\operatorname{com}A = 0$.

More can be said about the rank of $\operatorname{com}A$, but that's another question.